# Defining a quotient_type in Isabelle

Tags: equality, isabelle, isar

I'm still trying to reason over semantic equality in Isabelle.
I want to compare two formula and see whether they are equal. I've been told before, that i need quotienttypes for this. 
So i tried to define myself a quotiernttype, but apperently my definition is not complete since i don't seem to be abled to write any code after my definition.
My code so far is:

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin
no_notation plus (infixl "+" 65)

typedecl basicForm
datatype form_rep = af basicForm
axiomatization
equals ::  "form_rep ⇒ form_rep ⇒ bool" (infix "≐" 1) and
plus :: "form_rep ⇒ form_rep ⇒ form_rep" (infixl "+" 35)
  where
  reflexive: "x ≐ x" and
  symmetric: "x ≐ y ⟹ y ≐ x" and
  transitiv: "x ≐ y ⟹ y ≐ z ⟹ x ≐ z" and   

  commut:  "x + y         ≐ y + x"  and
  associatPlus:  "(x + y) + z  ≐ x + (y + z)"   and
  idemo:  "x + x           ≐ x" 

quotient_type formula = "form_rep" / "equals"
```

I've got some basic formula and complex version of it and i want to reason over the complex type, thus i defined equals with  the three axioms for equality relations and 3 additional easy axioms.

edit: Aparently i am an idiot who forgot to add quotationmarks -.-
still don't know how to continue from here on thought.

Answer (score 0):

The `quotient_type` commands requires a proof to be finished properly.  See the proof state output what needs to be proven.  Such things are explicitly or implicitly explained in the **isar-ref** manual.

Unrelated notes:

- Better avoid re-using elementary notation like `+`.  The *Symbols* panel in the Prover IDE provides plenty of alternatives.
- Better avoid free-form axiomatization, especially for initial examples.  Just take what Isabelle/HOL provides already, and make definitions on top of that (`datatype`, `definition`, `inductive`, `fun` etc.)
- Camel-case is not used in Isabelle.